# Storing data for HTML tables in database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm developing an application using PHP / SQL Server that needs to store information on graduates from tons of different academic programs, along with information on how many were employed after graduating... This will then be queried by users, who will want to compare one program to another, so they will need to be able to generate custom tables showing the outcomes for students. Tables will be something like this:

```
Program            Salary after 1 Year      Salary after 2 Years         Etc...
Engineering        Lots                     Even more!
Philosophy         Nothing                  Are you kidding me?
```

So, here's the question: should I store individual values for these data points in the database, or should I just store the raw HTML for the table row?

In other words, do I store this:

```
ProgramID    Salary1    Salary2               Etc...
1            Lots       Even More!
2            Nothing    Are you kidding me?
```

Or do I store this:

```
ProgramID   RowHTML
1           <td>Lots</td><td>Even More!</td>...
2           <td>Nothing</td><td>Are you kidding me?</td>
```

I can see arguments for both approaches... my gut tells me that storing the raw HTML will be faster - it will eliminate GOBS of PHP processing. But I'm open to other interpretations.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Rule for any RDBMS , only store the data in your tables and nothing else.

This will make your data retrieval, updated and insert operations fast, simple and safe . Store data in your tables and create HTML tables on runtime. I have demonstrated here how easy and simple it is to create HTML tables when you have only data stored in your table and nothing else.

**Example**

I have used your given example

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ProgramID INT,Salary1 VARCHAR(50),Salary2 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1,'Lots','Even More!'),
(2,'Nothing','Are you kidding me?')

DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<H1>Students Salaries</H1>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>ProgramID </th><th>Salary1</th><th>Salary2</th>' +
    CAST ( ( SELECT td = ProgramID,       
                    '',
                    td = Salary1, 
                    '',
                    td = Salary2
                FROM @t    

              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;
SELECT @tableHTML;
```

**HTML Table Created by the above query**

`<H1>Students Salaries</H1><table border="1"><tr><th>ProgramID </th><th>Salary1</th><th>Salary2</th><tr><td>1</td><td>Lots</td><td>Even More!</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Nothing</td><td>Are you kidding me?</td></tr></table>`

Comment: cute.  The next question will be, "how do I change the values?" - which would need to abstract the row objects.  But for quick and dirty displaying of data, this is functional.

Comment: @DanAndrews and my answer will be how much I will get paid for doing this for you :)

Comment: Thanks... this was actually my followup question... better to use PHP array processing to generate tables from the raw data, or to create a carefully-crafted SQL query to handle it?

I've got the coding down, so it's not a matter of needing code, it's just a matter of not knowing best practices...

(As a side note, my data will be pretty static... any updating would be a replacement of the entire table in question.)

Comment: @JohnChrysostom this query was for only demo purpose, and as I have already stated only store data into your tables and nothing else, it is actually the very 1st form of data normalization to store only one piece of information in one column, and use only one column to store a piece of information

Answer (score 0):

I would store the raw data only.  this will provide the ability to change the format/layout of the page when your boss says "Make it look newer" or whatever.  If you store the table data, you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

i think that storing individual values for these data points in the database will be better for managing the application , HTML is good but when you work with PHP-DATAbase is better , ... good luck dude.

Answer (score 0):

> So, here's the question: should I store individual values for these
>   data points in the database, or should I just store the raw HTML for
>   the table row?

Straight answer:

**Store the `data points`**, the html you can always recreate later, this will also make your queries way more fast.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Store the individual data, not the HTML.

There's no benefit to storing HTML here. Reproducing the table might be a little easier, but you're also storing a lot of redundant information, and building tables dynamically is not a difficult task to begin with. It's also much easier to manipulate raw data: when you're storing salaries over time as a single row of HTML, then you can only sort by program, but if you store each year individually and control the data type (your example salaries are strings, but you should be storing integers or floats, since you know that salary is an amount of money), you have the option of sorting programs by how much money graduates make out of college, ten years down the road, etc. Also bear in mind that you might not always want to display a table: you might want to graph the income over time for each major, for example, in which case you'd need to extract the salaries from the  and  tags, creating more work for yourself and slowing down the application.