# Fill HTML table with stored procedure SELECT statement output when using Dynamic SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I asked this question earlier, but left out an important piece of information (that I am using dynamic SQL). So, instead of editing it after it already received answers, I decided to open a new question. I am attempting to fill an HTML table from the output of a SELECT statement in a stored procedure when using dynamic sql.

I am using C# .NET MVC 4 and entity framework to execute the stored procedure. I have a query that is running in the stored procedure that looks something like:

```
  EXECUTE sp_executesql 
      N'SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee 
      WHERE BusinessEntityID = @level',
      N'@level tinyint',
      @level = 109;
```

I just stole this from MSDN, but the exact dynamic query doesn't matter.

Just pretend this returns about 50 rows. I am trying to get the output from the `SELECT` statement into an HTML table in my View. I haven't done this type of thing before so I am not sure of the best approach. Could that much data be sent back to the controller in output parameters. If so, I don't quite understand the approach to format that data into the `HTML` table.

I've done something similar before, but in that case I only had one row come back each time so I just sent the data back to the controller in output parameters and then sent it to my view in a `ViewBag`. What is the best approach with multiple rows?

EF doesn't appear to detect a result set because the query is built dynamically. So passing the results back is a bit confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: I answered a similar question sometime ago about rendering html from sql have a look at this [`Storing data for HTML tables in database`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120505/storing-data-for-html-tables-in-database), the query show in this answer puts the whole html in one variable, you can do the similar in dynamic sql and get the html in an `OUTPUT` parameter and use that wherever needed.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out. I'm exploring returning it as XML to the controller too.